# Does this scroll say 䤛食琴心?

Tags: translation, characters, traditional-characters

I was given the following scroll

[image: Scroll]

and would like a translation before I keep it up on my wall. I believe it says “䤛膳琴心” but I’m not sure. Moreover, I’m not familiar with this idiom and don’t know what it means (assuming those are the characters).

Comment: "剑胆琴心", 比喻既有情致，又有胆识（旧小说多用来形容能文能武的才子）。

Comment: 劍（剑）膽琴心 note that 剑 is written in simplified style.

Comment: bkrs,:courage of a warrior and the soul of a musician; the gall-bladder of a sword and the heart of a lute iciba: 琴心剑胆  have the soul of a musician and the courage of a warrior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

剑膽琴心（膽:Traditional Chinese,=胆）          德峰书

> 剑胆琴心/劍膽琴心：courage of a warrior and the soul of a musician; the gall-bladder of a sword and the heart of a lute.

This kind of work is used to describe and praise the people (especially the original owner or the author himself) who has both brave and lofty temperament/taste. It's something like 文武双全/文武雙全.